# HTTPS redirect not working for default backend of nginx-ingress-controller

Tags: ssl, nginx, kubernetes, amazon-elb, amazon-eks

I'm having trouble getting an automatic redirect to occur from HTTP -> HTTPS for the default backend of the NGINX ingress controller for kubernetes where the controller is behind an AWS Classic ELB; is it possible?

[According to the guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/) it seems like by default, HSTS is enabled

> HTTP Strict Transport Security
>   HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) is an opt-in security enhancement specified through the use of a special response header. Once a supported browser receives this header that browser will prevent any communications from being sent over HTTP to the specified domain and will instead send all communications over HTTPS.
>
> HSTS is enabled by default.

And redirecting HTTP -> HTTPS is enabled

> Server-side HTTPS enforcement through redirect
>   By default the controller redirects HTTP clients to the HTTPS port 443 using a 308 Permanent Redirect response if TLS is enabled for that Ingress.

However, when I deploy the controller as configured below and navigate to `http://<ELB>.elb.amazonaws.com` I am unable to get any response (curl reports `Empty reply from server`). What I would expect to happen instead is I should see a 308 redirect to https then a 404.

This question is similar: [Redirection from http to https not working for custom backend service in Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52552686/953327) but they resolved it by deploying a custom backend and specifying on the ingress resource to use TLS. I am trying to avoid deploying a custom backend and just simply want to use the default so this solution is not applicable in my case.

[I've shared my deployment files on gist](https://gist.github.com/fgreg/c6ac5ec678b790ac66afa2678627d6f6) and have copied them here as well:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx-sit
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-sit
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx-sit
spec:
  minReadySeconds: 2
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: '50%'
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-sit
      app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx-sit
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-sit
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx-sit
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/port: '10254'
        prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: nginx-ingress-serviceaccount
      containers:
        - name: nginx-ingress-controller
          image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.23.0
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-configuration
            - --annotations-prefix=nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
            - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx
            - --ingress-class=$(POD_NAMESPACE)
            - --election-id=leader
            - --watch-namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
              add:
                - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            # www-data -> 33
            runAsUser: 33
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 80
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 10
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 10

---

kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: ingress-nginx-sit
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-sit
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx-sit
data:
  hsts: "true"
  ssl-redirect: "true"
  use-proxy-protocol: "false"
  use-forwarded-headers: "true"
  enable-access-log-for-default-backend: "true"
  enable-owasp-modsecurity-crs: "true"
  proxy-real-ip-cidr: "10.0.0.0/24,10.0.1.0/24" # restrict this to the IP addresses of ELB
```

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx-sit
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-sit
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx-sit
  annotations:
    # replace with the correct value of the generated certificate in the AWS console
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:<region>:<account>:certificate/<id>"
    # Specify the ssl policy to apply to the ELB
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-negotiation-policy: "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01"
    # the backend instances are HTTP
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "http"
    # Terminate ssl on https port
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "*"
    # Ensure the ELB idle timeout is less than nginx keep-alive timeout. By default,
    # NGINX keep-alive is set to 75s. If using WebSockets, the value will need to be
    # increased to '3600' to avoid any potential issues.
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "60"
    # Security group used for the load balancer.
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-extra-security-groups: "sg-xxxxx"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-sit
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx-sit
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
    # Restrict allowed source IP ranges
    - "192.168.1.1/16"
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
      # The range of valid ports is 30000-32767
      nodePort: 30080
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: http
      # The range of valid ports is 30000-32767
      nodePort: 30443
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the problem.

For some reason the default server has `force_ssl_redirect` set to false when determining if it should redirect the incoming request to HTTPS:

`cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` notice the `rewrite_by_lua_block` sends `force_ssl_redirect = false`

```
...
    ## start server _
    server {
        server_name _ ;

        listen 80 default_server reuseport backlog=511;

        set $proxy_upstream_name "-";
        set $pass_access_scheme $scheme;
        set $pass_server_port $server_port;
        set $best_http_host $http_host;
        set $pass_port $pass_server_port;

        listen 443  default_server reuseport backlog=511 ssl http2;

        # PEM sha: 601213c2dd57a30b689e1ccdfaa291bf9cc264c3
        ssl_certificate                         /etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key                     /etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem;

        ssl_certificate_by_lua_block {
            certificate.call()
        }

        location / {

            set $namespace      "";
            set $ingress_name   "";
            set $service_name   "";
            set $service_port   "0";
            set $location_path  "/";

            rewrite_by_lua_block {
                lua_ingress.rewrite({
                    force_ssl_redirect = false,
                    use_port_in_redirects = false,
                })
                balancer.rewrite()
                plugins.run()
            }
...
```

Then, the LUA code requires `force_ssl_redirect` **and** `redirect_to_https()`

`cat /etc/nginx/lua/lua_ingress.lua`

```
...
  if location_config.force_ssl_redirect and redirect_to_https() then
    local uri = string_format("https://%s%s", redirect_host(), ngx.var.request_uri)

    if location_config.use_port_in_redirects then
      uri = string_format("https://%s:%s%s", redirect_host(), config.listen_ports.https, ngx.var.request_uri)
    end

    ngx_redirect(uri, config.http_redirect_code)
  end
...
```

From what I can tell the `force_ssl_redirect` setting is only [controlled at the Ingress resource](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-side-https-enforcement-through-redirect) level through the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"`. Because I don't have an ingress rule setup (this is meant to be the default server for requests that don't match any ingress), I have no way of changing this setting.

So what I determined I have to do is define my own custom server snippet on a different port that has `force_ssl_redirect` set to true and then point the Service Load Balancer to that custom server instead of the default. Specifically:

Added to the `ConfigMap`:

```
...
  http-snippet: |
    server {
      server_name _ ;
      listen 8080 default_server reuseport backlog=511;

      set $proxy_upstream_name "-";
      set $pass_access_scheme $scheme;
      set $pass_server_port $server_port;
      set $best_http_host $http_host;
      set $pass_port $pass_server_port;

      server_tokens off;
      location / {
        rewrite_by_lua_block {
            lua_ingress.rewrite({
                force_ssl_redirect = true,
                use_port_in_redirects = false,
            })
            balancer.rewrite()
            plugins.run()
        }
      }
      location /healthz {
        access_log off;
        return 200;
      }
    }
  server-snippet: |
    more_set_headers "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
```

**Note** I also added the `server-snippet` to enable HSTS correctly. I think because the traffic from the ELB to NGINX is HTTP not HTTPS, the HSTS headers were not being correctly added by default.

Added to the `DaemonSet`:

```
...
        ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 80
          - name: http-redirect
            containerPort: 8080
...
```

Modified the `Service`:

```
...
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
...
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http-redirect
      # The range of valid ports is 30000-32767
      nodePort: 30080
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: http
      # The range of valid ports is 30000-32767
      nodePort: 30443
...
```

And now things seem to be working. I've updated [the Gist](https://gist.github.com/fgreg/c6ac5ec678b790ac66afa2678627d6f6) so it includes the full configuration that I am using.